# Enviar notificação para os usuário on-line dentro do sistema

Tags: php, javascript, json

Como faço para que meu sistema após enviar um registro para o bd, os usuários que estão on-line recebam por notificação tal ação.
Exemplo:
Usuário(a), adicionou um cliente em uma fila de espera, nesse momento o sistema grava esse registro na tabela de fila de espera, na ação seguinte o sistema enviaria para um determinar grupo de usuários(on-line) que tal cliente esta na fila de espera.
até consegui fazer, mas as notificações só aparece para o usuário que esta trabalhando, os demais não recebem nada.

Comment: Que banco está utilizando? O Firebase possui uma opção de leitura em que dados são atualizados quando houver alguma mudança no banco

Comment: estou usando mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu também já passei por isso ao tentar implementar uma funcionalidade que alterasse o front-end em tempo real.

O que consegui achar de interessante para solucionar este problema foi sobre sockets. Como tem as tags PHP e javascript suponho que seja para web, logo mais especificamente pode procurar por WebSockets.

Existem ferramentas prontas (chamadas de hosted) e outras que auxiliam na implementação (self-hosted).
Das hosted, a que eu mais gostei foi o Pusher.
Já das self-hosted achei o Ratchet, para PHP, muito boa e mais fácil de trabalhar, porém existe uma mais completa chamada ReactPHP.

Também pode usar o Firebase, um serviço da Google, que tem a funcionalidade de real-time database. Adaptando ela para as suas necessidades também é possível usá-la para este propósito.